# C++11 making sure primitive types are passed in the right order

Tags: c++, templates

Lets say I have a constructor or a method with 3 integer arguments.

Object.h

```
Object::Object(int alenght, int awidth, int aheight);
```

Is there a way to make sure at compile type that I pass them in the right order?

```
int l = 10;
int w = 15;
int h = 5;
```

main.cpp

```
Object myObject(l,w,h); // is correct
Object myObject(w,l,h); // incorrect but compiles
```

Of course I could create a class for each integer but that's pretty time intensive. 
Is there a way, based on templates probably to generate an error at compile time, without needing to create a class for each integer?

Comment: Nope. You could write a single boilerplate adaptor for a number type, but add an empty class as a tag, and that way it would be a single template class of boilerplate, but 3 classes to ensure you're passing arguments in the correct order. `template <typename Int, typename Tag> class int_adaptor {...};`

Comment: You might just want to use a struct that you construct only via explicit member assignment (no parameters constructor). s.width = w, s.height = ... It's harder to make mistakes  that way.

Comment: @synchronizer: Arguably, with more typing required, it's easier to make mistakes that way.

Comment: I think the tradeoff is okay since you at least don't have to worry about the order in which you do assignment, which is the main issue here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the current version of C++ there's nothing simple you can do. The next version of C++ will allow something like:

```
Object myObject = { .length = 10, .width = 15, .height = 5 };
```

---

In the meantime you would have to use some sort of hack, e.g. define a separate type for each parameter so that the compiler can report type mismatches. Here's a code sample:

```
struct Object
{
    int length, width, height;

    struct Length { explicit Length(int x): x(x) {}; int x; };
    struct Width  { explicit Width(int x):  x(x) {}; int x; };
    struct Height { explicit Height(int x): x(x) {}; int x; };

    Object(Length length, Width width, Height height):
        length(length.x), width(width.x), height(height.x)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Object obj( Object::Length(10), Object::Width(15), Object::Height(5) );
}
```

Comment: There's only so far you can babysit a developer @RemyLebeau. Use apps hungarian notation if you're so concerned for all variables. It doesn't allow compile-time enforcement, but helps prevent bad developer practices.

Answer (score 2):

You could use tags to create a single integer (or numeric) adaptor, and then allow only allow the proper types to be passed to the argument, minimizing the amount of boilerplate.

```
struct l_tag {};
struct w_tag {};
struct h_tag {};

template <typename Int, typename Tag>
struct int_adaptor
{
public:
    explicit int_adaptor(Int x = Int()):
        data_(x)
    {}

    // ....

private:
    Int data_;
};

using l_type = int_adaptor<int, l_tag>;
using w_type = int_adaptor<int, w_tag>;
using h_type = int_adaptor<int, h_tag>;
```

This would allow compile-time enforcement of the proper type signatures, and minimize the boilerplate. However, in practice, it may be more boilerplate than desired.

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no. The only way to do this is to make each parameter be a different type, and ensure that each type can't be passed in as another type. You could write a single template class to wrap the integers, and then specialize it for each parameter type based on an enum, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

No.

There are three integers and neither the language nor the compiler has any way at all of knowing what they "mean", unless you introduce some type-safety (but you've ruled that out).

The conventional way to handle this is with *testing*.